# $X_n$ are independent exponential variables, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty λ_n^{-1}=\infty$,show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n=\infty$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ be independent nonnegative random variables, with $X_n$ having density $λ_n\exp(-λ_n x),x\geq 0,λ_n\geq 0$,if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty λ_n^{-1}=\infty$, show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n=\infty$ a.e.

Attempts:$\sum_{n=1}^\infty λ_n^{-1}=\infty$ implies $\sum_n E(X_n)=E(\sum_n X_n)=\infty$,also I get a hint to try to consider $\exp(-\sum_nX_n)$,and from $X_n$ are independent,$E(\exp(-\sum_nX_n))=\Pi_n E(\exp(-X_n))$, but I don't know what to do next?

A very similar question:[Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be independent r.v.'s with $0 \leq X_n \leq 1$ and $\sum_n E(X_n) = \infty$. Show $\sum_n X_n = \infty$ with probability 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575240) but differs in $0\leq X_n\leq 1$

Comment: The $X_n$ are exponential variables, not Poisson - the title should be changed

Comment: [Kolmogorov three-series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem) makes quick work of this.

Comment: @MikeEarnest But $X_n$ is unbounded,then how to use Kolmogorov three-series theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n^{-1}$ does. If $\sum_{x=1}^\infty X_n<\infty$ then for all $s>0$ we have
$$
0<\mathbb E\left[e^{-s\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n}\right] = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb E[e^{-sX_n}] = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_n+s}.
$$
This infinite product converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_n+s}\right)$ does (as can be shown by considering the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\log\left(\frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_n+s}\right)$ ), and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_n+s}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac s{s+\lambda_n}
$$
converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n^{-1}$ does.

Conversely, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n^{-1}<\infty$, then by monotone convergence, $$\mathbb \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb E[X_n] = \mathbb E\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n\right]<\infty,$$ and hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n<\infty$ as the $X_n$ are almost surely nonnegative.

Comment: Why does $\sum X_n < \infty$ a.e imply E(exp($-s\sum X_n$)) converges a.e?

Comment: @qmww987 Did you actually read my answer? I went on to explain that in detail...

Comment: Sorry but if I hadn't misunderstand your answer,you state that $∑X_n<∞$  a.e implies $E(\exp(−s\sum X_n))$ converges a.e,and you show that $E(\exp(−s\sum X_n))$ converges a.e iff $\sum_n\lambda_n^{-1}$ converges(which are in detail), but you didn't explain why   $∑X_n<∞$  a.e implies $E(\exp(−s\sum X_n))$ converges a.e?

Comment: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ is infinite then $e^{-s\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$....

Comment: I see.But it should be: $E(\exp(−s\sum X_n))$  doesn't converge to 0 a.e instead of $E(\exp(−s\sum X_n))$  doesn't converge a.e,actually $E(\exp(−s\sum X_n))$  always converges.